# Using the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, gradle, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a web app using java and spring-boot as the backend.
I want to use the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method of FirebaseAuth in order to create a new user in my firebase database.

This is init of the FirebaseAuth object:

```
private final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

I'm trying to access createUserWithEmailAndPassword from the mAuth object but it does not recognize the method, it can only find:

`mAuth.createUser(CreateRequest request);`
or
`mAuth.createUserAsync(CreateRequest request);`

The project is build with gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.0.0'
}
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method only exists in the client-side SDKs of Firebase, such as those for use in Web and Android apps.

You are using the Admin SDK for Java, which is made for using in server-side code such as yours. The Admin SDKs do not have a `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, but you can [create a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) by calling `createUser` as shown in the link.